# Retrieve struct epoll_event from socket that has not been triggered

Tags: epoll

I have dynamically allocated memory and stored it in a struct epoll_event which was then registered to a socket for epoll to monitor. There are times that I need to close this socket before the event has triggered. If I close the socket, the event and dynamically allocated memory is lost. Is there a way to retrieve it from epoll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. If you are monitoring for EPOLLRDHUP, you can call `shutdown(soc, SHUT_RDWR)`. This will trigger your socket and allow your handler to clean up. It would be nice to be able to trigger a socket without shutting down the connection, but I do not think that is possible.